# pass a variable from view to controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the method in the controller:

```
def sort
    case params[:order_param]
    when "title"  
    @cars = Movie.find(:all, :order => 'title')
    when "rating"
    @cars = Movie.find(:all, :order => 'rating')
else "release"
    @cars = Movie.find(:all, :order => 'release_date')
end
    redirect_to cars_path
end
```

This is the view:

```
%th= link_to "Car Title", :action => 'sort', :order_param => 'title'
%th= link_to "Rating", :action => 'sort', :order_param => 'rating'
%th= link_to "Release Date", :action => 'sort', :order_param => 'release'
```

If I open the index page, this error message appears:

```
No route matches {:action=>"sort", :order_param=>"title", :controller=>"cars"}
```

Result of the "rake routes" command

```
cars      GET    /cars(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"cars"}
          POST   /cars(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"cars"}
new_car   GET    /cars/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"cars"}
edit_car  GET    /cars/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"cars"}
car       GET    /cars/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cars"}
      PUT    /cars/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"cars"}
      DELETE /cars/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"cars"}
```

Comment: do you have sort defined in routes in cars resources?

Comment: can you give the result of the "rake routes" command please?

Comment: This appears to be a missing parameter for your target. Wherever possible, use named routes to avoid this sort of thing.

Comment: As an additional note, `Movie.order('rating').all` is the more modern way of expressing this kind of logic. Many examples use `find` in all kinds of creative ways that are no longer necessary.

Comment: @PriteshJ I haven't defined sort in routes. :action => 'sort' should means do function sort in cars_controller.rb

Comment: @Dougui result of rake routes is in edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a sort method (or a redirect) at all. You can put that code into your index method since you want to display index.html.haml (sorting 'cars' should not send you to a new page, right?)

```
def index                                                                      
  order_param = params[:order_param]                              
  case order_param                                                                
  when 'title'                                                                 
    ordering = {:order => :title}
  when 'release_date'                                                          
    ordering = {:order => :release_date}
  end

  @cars = Movie.find_all(ordering)
end
```

Comment: As for removing the case statement, I think it's best to leave it in your code. It helps to validate input, since there are only two values you want to handle. Without the case statement, someone could type in a url where params[:order_param] is not valid. That value would then get passed on to the DB request (not good).

Answer (score 1):

Dry it up first of all.  There's no need for that switch/case.

```
def sort
  @cars = Movie.order(params[:order_param])
  redirect_to cars_path
end
```

Secondly, it looks like you don't have a `sort` route defined in your `routes.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help guys, this is solution i was searching (very similar to mehtunguh solution). Sorry for misunderstandings, I'm new to rails.

```
 def index
    case params[:order_param]
    when "title"  
          @cars = Movie.find(:all, :order => 'title')
    when "rating"
          @cars = Movie.find(:all, :order => 'rating')
    when "release"
          @cars = Movie.find(:all, :order => 'release_date')
    else
          @cars = Movie.all
      end
  end
```