# How to pass a value from a view to another action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view new.html.erb for a controller (ratings)

The view has a form

```
<"form action="/ratings/create" method="post"">
```

I need to pass a value from the view that is not a part of the form to the action create.

I tried doing `action="/ratings/create:100"` but it fails.

Thanks

Comment: you will have to add it as a hidden element in the form.

Comment: There are many answers to this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672155/passing-parameters-from-view-to-controller
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770052/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-controller-action-from-view-in-rails-through-link-to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851090/pass-a-variable-from-view-to-controller-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I was hoping there could be a way without using link to

Comment: Adding hidden element works and I was wondering how can I pass it using action in form

Comment: try `action="/ratings/create?value=100"`